# Using Windows Batch write quoted parameters to a File

Tags: batch-file

Firstly I'm trying to delete the contents of a file and re-write them using Windows Batch.
Here's what I've managed so far

```
break>params.xml

echo "<test>testid="test"<test>" > params.xml
pause
```

How can I remove the quotes surrounding the outer test tag but keep the quotes on the testid parameter?

In the end my params XML file should contain only:

```
<test>testid="test"<test>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try escape characters. Here is a reference: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: I would put that as answer, but I have no way of testing it right now. Hope it will do though

Comment: Is your quoted string in a variable, including the encasing quotes?

Comment: No, I literally want to output <test>testid="test"<test>

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the escape sequences as [DaMaxContent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3186555/damaxcontent) proposed.
If you dont like this you can use FOR command:

```
C:\>set "string=<test>testid="test"<test>"

C:\>for /f "tokens=* delims=" %# in ("%string%") do ((@echo(%#)>>params.xml)
```

for usage from batch file you'll need double `%`.

For more convenient usage from command line you can create two simple macros:

```
>set "output=for /f "tokens=* delims=" %# in ("
>set "to=) do @(echo(%#)>"
>%output% "<special string>"  %to% file
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "string=<test>testid="test"<test>"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set string') DO ECHO %%b
set "string=%string:<=^<%"
set "string=%string:>=^>%"

echo(%string%

GOTO :EOF
```

Here are two ways, assuming that your string is literal and not already in  a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you just be able to delimit them with `^`?

```
echo ^<test^>testid^=^"test^"^<test^> > params.xml
```

Or if you're feeling really cautious:

```
echo ^<test^>testid^=^"test^"^<test^> > params.xml
```